# svg rotate 90deg but disappear

Tags: css, svg

I have a svg which is an arrow facing right. However, i am unable to make the arrow downward by adding transform: rotate(). When I change css svg path, the entire arrow is gone. How do I solve it?

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

In my html and css,

```css
svg path {
transform: rotate(90);
}
```

```html
<svg class="arrow-right" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 25 25">
 <g id="ico___black" data-name="ico_&gt;_black" transform="translate(19525 16160)">
   <path id="パス_60" data-name="パス 60" d="M1061.961,192.633l5.465,5.465,5.465-5.465"
     transform="translate(-19707.389 -15080.434) rotate(-90)" fill="none" stroke="#2b2525"
     stroke-width="2" />
   <rect id="長方形_124" data-name="長方形 124" width="25" height="25" transform="translate(-19525 -16160)" 
     fill="none" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Try transform the `svg`  not the `svg path`

Comment: please use this svg instead: much cleaner without so many transformations: `<svg width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>navigate next</title>
    <path d='M10 6l-1.41 1.41 4.58 4.59-4.58 4.59 1.41 1.41 6-6z'></path>
    <path d='M0 0h24v24h-24z' fill='none'></path>
</svg>` Also in CSS you need to do: `svg path {
transform: rotate(90deg);
transform-origin: center center;
}` In CSS the rotation happens around the 0,0 point. That's why you need to transform the origin to the center

Comment: To understand what happens if you don't transform the origin add svg{overflow:visible} to your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply the transform on the svg instead of the path.

```
svg {    
  transform: rotate(90);
}
```